# How to mock psycopg2's close connection?

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I'd like to test my DB class using psycopg2, but I met the problem - I have no idea how to test close() method. I've tried some ideas and that's the last one below and it's not working. So anyone knows how to mock that?

db.py

```
import psycopg2


class DB:
    def __init__(self, name: str) -> None:
        self.name = name
        self.conn = psycopg2.connect(dbname=self.name,
                                     host="localhost",
                                     port="5432",
                                     user="postgres",
                                     password="postgres")
        
    def disconnect(self):
        self.conn.close()
```

test_db.py

```
import unittest
from unittest import mock

import psycopg2

from db import DB


class TestDB(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self) -> None:
        self.db = DB("testdb")

    def tearDown(self) -> None:
        self.db.disconnect()

    @mock.patch("db.psycopg2.connect")
    def test_DB_should_connect_to_db(self, mock_connect):
        DB("testdb")
        mock_connect.assert_called_with(dbname="testdb",
                                        host="localhost",
                                        port="5432",
                                        user="postgres",
                                        password="postgres")

    @mock.patch("db.psycopg2.connect")
    def test_db_should_disconnect_from_db(self, mock_connect):
        mock_conn = mock_connect.return_value
        mock_close = mock_conn.close
        self.db.disconnect()
        mock_close.assert_called_once()





if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Comment: What do you think about different approach. Namely instead of creating connection in constructor you could pass to the constructor factory creating connections, like `connection_factory = lambda: …`. With such approach you're not bound to any specific db engine, neither you're not passing any dbrelated configuratio like credentials/host/etc. Such approach is also cleaner from OOP point of view – you're not creating your dependencies, you're asking for them. Obviously that approach is also easier to test.